# Why does scanf return a positive value even when the input is larger than the numercial type given?

Tags: c

Given the following code :

```
int x;
int r = scanf("%d", &x);
```

why is scanf returning `1` when the user inputs a number larger than `INT_MAX` or even larger than `LONG_MAX`?

From the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf#Return_value):

```
Number of receiving arguments successfully assigned.
```

Why is `x` considered successfully assigned? What does it mean exactly in this context? When the user gives numbers between `INT_MAX` and `LONG_MAX`, `x` appears to be the lower half of the result. I know `scanf` uses `strtol` internally but `scanf` could determine that the type `int` is too small to contain the result. Further, when passing a giant number, larger than `LONG_MAX`, the value of `x` is `-1` and the return value is *still* `1` and I have to rely on `errno` to check that something went wrong (`errno == ERANGE`).

What does "successfully assigned" mean and why does `scanf` return `1` given that it could so easily tell that the result is, in fact, garbage?

Comment: Note that `scanf` would return 1 even with an input like `123a`.

Comment: "scanf could determine that the type int is too small to contain the result." --> Yes it could, but the function is not defined to do so.  Now if your were around 40 years ago things may have been different.  (Remember then memory cost maybe 10,000x times what it does today)

Comment: You need to write your own converting function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot rely on `errno == ERANGE` or such in portable C programs.

`fscanf` is not documented authoritatively on cppreference.com, but in the ISO C standard. Firstly, the standard states that

> 16. The fscanf function returns the value of the macro `EOF` if an input failure occurs before the first conversion (if any) has completed. Otherwise, **the function returns the number of input items assigned**, which can be fewer than provided for, or even zero, in the event of an early matching failure.

I.e. nowhere does it contain the word "successful".

On the contrary, it says:

> [...] if the result of the conversion cannot be represented in the object, the behavior is undefined.

I.e. unfortunately there are no guarantees of behaviour in this case. In particular the standard never states that the result would be the largest number, or that `errno` would contain `ERANGE` or any other such thing.

Answer (score 1):

> why is scanf returning 1 when the user inputs a number larger then INT_MAX or even larger than LONG_MAX?

It is *undefined behavior* (UB) when the input text converts to outside the `int` range for `"%d"`.  It is a specification weakness of `scanf()`.
Anything may happen.

Robust code separates input from conversion.  Look to `fgets()` and `strtol()`.

Answer (score 0):

"scanf" is a function that reads data with specified format from a given string stream source. It allows the programmer to accept input from the standard input device (keyboard) and stores them in variables.

"scanf" stands for 'scan format', because it scans the input for valid tokens and parses them according to a specified format.

Reads a real number that (by default) the user has typed in into the variable miles

- Each variable must be preceded by the ampersand (&) address-of operator.
- We can read values into multiple variables with a single scanf as long as we have corresponding format strings for each variable.

"scanf" successfully accomplishing the 'scan format' function. It's not the function of "scanf" to check for the range for corresponding datatype.

Answer (score -2):

Remember that scanf (and its brothers and sisters) is a variadic function. There's value in telling the caller how many arguments were successfully assigned, where "successfully" might mean less than you think it does. It's the responsibility of the caller to make sure the arguments agree.